# how to get unique country timezones using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

how to get unique country timezones using momentjs?

Example:

```
Usa: 
Central Daylight Time (GMT-5)

Mountain Daylight Time (GMT-6)
...
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/getting-country-zones/

Comment: Okay so I found out long time before that there're services who provide API for more than $400 per year for what i needed, but you keep downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

A rough solution would be something like:

```
zones = moment.tz.zonesForCountry('US').map((z) => {
  tzone = moment.tz.zone(z)
  abbr = moment.tz(z).format('z')
  time = tzone.parse(Date.now())
  return `${z.replace("America/", "")} ${abbr}(GMT-${time / 60})`
} )
console.info(zones)
```

Returns following:

```
["Adak HDT(GMT-9)","Anchorage AKDT(GMT-8)","Boise MDT(GMT-6)","Chicago CDT(GMT-5)","Denver MDT(GMT-6)","Detroit EDT(GMT-4)","Indiana/Indianapolis EDT(GMT-4)","Indiana/Knox CDT(GMT-5)","Indiana/Marengo EDT(GMT-4)","Indiana/Petersburg EDT(GMT-4)","Indiana/Tell_City CDT(GMT-5)","Indiana/Vevay EDT(GMT-4)","Indiana/Vincennes EDT(GMT-4)","Indiana/Winamac EDT(GMT-4)","Juneau AKDT(GMT-8)","Kentucky/Louisville EDT(GMT-4)","Kentucky/Monticello EDT(GMT-4)","Los_Angeles PDT(GMT-7)","Menominee CDT(GMT-5)","Metlakatla AKDT(GMT-8)","New_York EDT(GMT-4)","Nome AKDT(GMT-8)","North_Dakota/Beulah CDT(GMT-5)","North_Dakota/Center CDT(GMT-5)","North_Dakota/New_Salem CDT(GMT-5)","Phoenix MST(GMT-7)","Sitka AKDT(GMT-8)","Yakutat AKDT(GMT-8)","Pacific/Honolulu HST(GMT-10)"]
```

Assumes the knowledge that US timezones are behind GMT (GMT-)

Comment: i need common name of timezone, not like "America/Los_Angeles" but "Pacific Daylight Time"

Comment: @BashLord again, did you read [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/)? Also, since your question is asking for zones _per-country_, what are the _"common names"_ for timezones outside the US?

Comment: GMT Standard Time, Eastern Standard Time. Abrr like "AST" is same for Argentina Standard Time, Arabic Standard Time, Arab Standard Time, Afghanistan Standard Time.  seems like moment does't  have it

Comment: @BashLord This library does not provide common names. However if you know the common names, there is a work around described in the documentation.